# windows.h library on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, libraries

I wanted to make an application for android and I need to use Sleep() but windows.h library doesn't work with android, sa how can I use waiting time on Android ? (using Qt c++)

Please answer me exactly what I must to do and where in code, in which file (headers/source/main), and how can I use this function(example)

Comment: In 21st century C++ it's `std::this_thread::sleep_for` but Android isn't the most modern system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> QThread also provides static, platform independent sleep functions:
>   sleep(), msleep(), and usleep() allow full second, millisecond, and
>   microsecond resolution respectively.

So you can simply:

`QThread::msleep(ms);`

It will cause the current thread you are in to sleep for ms milliseconds. You need to `#include <QThread>` obviously.

Comment: Thanks this is answer I was waiting for, everything works ;)